# Make report fields align bottom with a 'grow able' field

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I've been stuck for quite a while now on a *small* problem using Crystal Reports. I've been trying to make other fields grow along side a text object (or paragraph) so they all align nicely to the bottom.

[image: img1]

Here you can see all the fields I have in the 'problematic' zone.

[image]

The field where my cursor is a quite unpredictable element which has the option to grow (can grow)

[image]

However I want the blue fields in the picture above to be at the same height as the last line of the grow able field (in red)

[image]

As you can see in the picture above this isn't the case, it is where I placed the fields in crystal reports. (red field has multiple lines, blue lines are 'floating'in space :( )

[image]

How I would like it to be (With multiple lines for the red field, even though it's only one line now.)

Any suggestions would be nice.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I would play with two sections (one for growing field, another for remaining ones) and 'underlay following section' option - although quite unlikely that even this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a one more section of where you placed fields and in first section place the can grow field and in second section place all other fields.

For first section check the option `underlay following sections`.

This will solve your issue.. tested the solution

Comment: This overlaps the text. I tried it. I'll try to do it again later today after I fixed my current issue with different ADO datatables for subreports.